# Ajax call only passing id of the first element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am outputting multiple dynamic links which use the same < a >. My AJAX call loads the content fine of all the links fine. But the new div which displays the ajax content only outputs id of the first link when other links are clicked. I am using this to see the id in the console `console.log($('[data-taskid]').first().attr('data-id'));` how can i pass the id of the link clicked to my ajax view? Thanks guys!

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
$string .= '<a class="hrefid" data-id="'.$name["id"].'" href="#link">'.$name["name"].'</a>'.
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.hrefid').on('click', function (e) {
    var load = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if(load == "#link") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/page/test/"+$(this).parents("[data-id]").attr("data-id"),
            complete: function (event) {
                $("#content").contents().remove();
                $("#content").append(event.responseText);


            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `parents()` in your code?

Comment: You should use `this` instead of `e.target ` so your code should be `var load= $(this).attr('href');`

Comment: And the `.parents();`is not required so take that out and use `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Comment: I am using this now, but doesn't help with the data passing though

Comment: I don't see `console.log($('[data-taskid]').first().attr('data-taskid'));` in your code, but that could cause output of the "first link when other links are clicked". It might help to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue. I suggest using some static test links (no php) and contrasting the url generated by your JavaScript with your desired output.

Comment: It should be  there was typo `console.log($('[data-taskid]').first().attr('data-id'));` I am using this on the page that I am calling using ajax to test what id is being passed on.

Answer (score 1):

Please review that I didn't use $(this) as reference , $(this) reference get chnaged once you use $(this) in ajax , it refers to ajax not main selector.

```
       $('.hrefid').on('click', function (e) {
              var $this = $(this);
              var load = $this.attr("href");
              if(load == "#link") {
                    $.ajax({
                         type: 'post',
                         url: "/page/test/"+ $this.attr("data-id"),
                         complete: function (event) {
                             $("#content").contents().remove();
                             $("#content").append(event.responseText);
                         }
                    });
              }
        });
```

Comment: I am using var `$this = $(this);` although it changes the id in the url when a linked is clicked, but it doesn't pass the id to the ajax view

Comment: Please try this : $this.data('id') and also try $this.prop('data-id')

Comment: I tried both of them neither worked, I was able to use both to load the correct view but once the view loaded can't get any other id than the first link